# How to make a parallax effect on an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

Does anyone know how to do parallax effect on an image when hover?

:(

this is the link example:

```
http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-moving-perspective/full_screen_preview/4522271
```

I would appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect is "Parallax". You can use this library to make it easily http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/jquery4u-parallax-demo/

Comment: Thank you!!! Just one last question is there a way to make the image itself vertical instead of horizontal, I can´t find not even one website that has vertical image slider, if I want more images can it be added to this Parallax function?

Comment: You mean like that? http://bxslider.com/examples/vertical-slideshow

Comment: not exactly  it´s horizontal ,I dont mean by slider effect but the whole frame vertical, is it possible?

Comment: Like that? http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php#vertical XD

Comment: like the " horz3" from this image link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oDpes.png   Just occupying one third of the website placing it on the right, with the parallax can I make it vertical instead of horizontal? Lo agradeceria muchísimo!!

Comment: Sorry I've never done that :(

Comment: muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda, ya ire averiguando si es posible, gracias de nuevo, cuidate